# 4 columns in smarty

Tags: php, apache, smarty

Is this even on the same planet as the correct code format in smarty.

```
   {foreach from=$watchvendor item=item}            
   <td><a href="{$vendorUrl}?vid={$item.id}">{$item.id} - {$item.nick}</a></td>
   {math equation= 'x/y' x=$item y='4' assign='howmany'}
   {if $howmany eq 0}
   </tr>
   <tr>
   {/if}      
  {/foreach}
```

i assume that $item is the element identity in the array ie.. 0 1 2 3 4 5 so when that did not work i tried this as well

```
{math equation=" 'x/y' x=count($watchvendor) y='4' assign='howmany'}
```

so basically if the loop divided by 4 = 0 its time for a new row.

The basic code without the extra math works fine i just want it spread out on the page.

ok i used

```
{$item|@debug_print_var}
```

and got this

```
Array (2)
  id => 8
  nick => "bbuddy" Array (2)
  id => 7
  nick => "span" Array (2)
  id => 6
  nick => "LJ" Array (2)
  id => 5
  nick => "JD" Array (2)
  id => 4
  nick => "Jsmith159"
```

sure is a strange looking array, first time i have ever seen a smarty array - no element id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
  <table class="ow_table_1 ow_form ow_automargin">
  <tr> 
   {assign var=cnt value=0}      
   {foreach from=$watchvendor item=item}
   {assign var=cnt value=$cnt+1}                        
   <td><a href="{$vendorUrl}?vid={$item}">{$item.id} - {$item.nick}</a></td>
   {if $cnt eq 4}
   </tr>
   <tr>
   {assign var=cnt value=0}
   {/if}
   {/foreach}
  </tr>
</table>
```